# How to encode (replace) parts of word from end to beginning for some N value (like abcabcab to cbacbaba for n=3)?

Tags: python, string, replace, encoding, character-encoding

I would like to create a program for encoding and decoding words.
Specifically, the program should take part of the word (count characters depending on the value of n) and turns them backwards.
This cycle will be running until it encodes the whole word.

At first I created the number of groups of parts of the word which is the number of elements n + some possible remainder
*(For example for Language with n = 3 has 3 parts - two parts of 3 chars and one remainder with 2 chars).This unit is called a **general**.

Then, depending on the general, I do a cycle that n * takes the given character and always adds it to the group (group has n chars).

At the end of the group cycle, I add (in reverse order) to new_word and reset the group value.
The goal should be to example decode word **Language** *with (n value = 2)* to **aLgnaueg**. 
Or **Language** with (n value = 3) to **naL aug eg** and so on. 
Next example is word **abcabcab** (n=3) to **cba cba ba** ?

Output of my code don´t do it right. Output for n=3 is "naLaugeg"

Could I ask how to improve it? **Is there some more simple python function how to rewrite it**?

My code is there:

```
n = 3
word = "Language"


new_word = ""

group = ""

divisions =  (len(word)//n)
residue =  (len(word)%n)
general = divisions + residue

for i in range(general):
    j=2
    
    for l in range(n):
        group += word[i+j]
        print(word[i+j], l)
        j=j-1
    
    
    for j in range((len(group)-1),-1,-1):
        new_word += group[j]
        print(word[j])
        
    group = ""
    
    
print(group)    

print(new_word)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import textwrap

n = 3
word = "Language"


chunks = textwrap.wrap(word, n)
reversed_chunks = [chunk[::-1] for chunk in chunks]

>>> print(' '.join(reversed_chunks))
naL aug eg
```

Comment: Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you know, how to replace whole sentence like this?  _print(decode(3, encode(3, "This sentence could be encrypted and decrypted agai")))_ Thank´s