# How to correctly encrypt and decrypt sentence in one calling by function?

Tags: python, string, function, chunked-encoding

I would like to encrypt and decrypt this sentence in this one calling.
So output will be same as input. 
But instead of I see *This sentence coule dncbypeedrndtecaypdedrgatina* in input.
Is there somebody who knows how to solve it? 
Thank you

```
import textwrap

def encode(n: int, word: str) -> str:
    
    chunks = textwrap.wrap(word, n)
    reversed_chunks = [chunk[::-1] for chunk in chunks]
    #print(''.join(reversed_chunks))
    return(''.join(reversed_chunks))
   
def decode(n: int, word_back: str) -> str: #

    chunks = textwrap.wrap(word_back, n)
    reversed_chunks = [chunk[::-1] for chunk in chunks]
    #print(''.join(reversed_chunks))
    return(''.join(reversed_chunks))
    
print(decode(3, encode(3, "This sentence could be encrypted and decrypted again")))
```

Comment: did you check how `textwrap.wrap` works? And if you can use it in this way?

Comment: So I am not able to do it with this. So do you know how to solve this problem by another method?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Call both functions by this _print(decode(3, encode(3, "This sentence could be encrypted and decrypted again")))_

Comment: uh ... I just checked `textwrap.wrap`, and it's a function that splits the string into `n`-long parts. How is that encrypting?

Comment: it also removes the spaces if they are between words

Comment: I would like to do this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573359/how-to-encode-replace-parts-of-word-from-end-to-beginning-for-some-n-value-li] and somebody recomend me textwrap.wrap. I need to do it also with this example: _print(decode(3, encode(3, "This sentence could be encrypted and decrypted again")))_

Comment: well, as you can see, it only works for words, not full messages with spaces

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Ok. Nad is there some method how to run it with spaces?

Comment: you could make a function that does it manually

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I know and I tried there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573359/how-to-encode-replace-parts-of-word-from-end-to-beginning-for-some-n-value-li but my result was wrong: "LanangnguguaL"

Comment: `"".join([string[i:i+3][::-1] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)])`

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Thank you